# Evaluate cell which uses named field in its formula - Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsm

I'm having a problem evaluating excel sheet cell which uses named cell in its formula. I'm using **apache-poi version 3.17**, **java 1.8** and the file I'm working with is **.xlsm**. Here is an example code:

```
//Getting the excel file from the database
Document doc = documentRepository.findByDocumentType(DocumentType.EXAMPLE);
InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.getFileData());
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
Sheet mappingSheet = workbook.getSheet("Quote services");

FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

// This cell contains a formula which uses named cell
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A109");
Row row = mappingSheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```

This gives me the following error:

> org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range
>   'Discount' does not exist in the current workbook.

The excel formula looks something like that:

```
=Discount*A7
```

Where Discount is `A5` and if I change the formula to look like this:

```
=A5*A7
```

it works fine.

This is kind of strange cause if I try to get the named field `Discount` it finds it, but if I use `evaluate` on a cell which uses the field it doesn't.

The document is predefined so I can't change anything in it. If I name the given discount cell with poi and with the same name there is no problem, but I don't want to do this cause there are more named fields in the document and if something change I have to change the code. Any help will be appreciated!

**I found the problem! It was that the `Discount` field was referenced from a hidden sheet in the document and it was referenced like this: `Discount` instead of `'Quote services'!Discount`.**

Comment: Please show the output of `Name name = workbook.getName("Discount"); System.out.println(name.getNameName() + " refers to " + name.getRefersToFormula());`

Comment: This is the output: `Discount refers to 'Quote services'!$AO$10` The above were example cells this is the real one (not that it matters).

Comment: Then I cannot reproducing this behavior. The formula `=IF(A1="NO",A13*(1-Discount),A13*(1-M13))` results in a value in  the `Excel` sheet if  `A1="NO"`? Or does it shows `#Name?` then?

Comment: It has to show the discount in given currency (double number). Depending on `A1` it chooses the right way to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Discount` is indeed within the Workbook that you are evaluating? The message is pretty clear.

Can you show exactly how the formula looks like - is it something like this:

```
=SUM('C:\Data\[Finances.xlsx]Discount'!D10:D25)
```

Try `setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks(true)`, and if it works, then the `Discount` is set in another workbook. [setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks(boolean)).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It is in the same Workbook. If I try to get it like this: `Name name = workbook.getName("Discount")` it finds it. The formula looks something like this `=IF(A1="NO",A13*(1-Discount),A13*(1-M13))`

Comment: In the calculations, there are some cells which are in a different sheet, but in the same workbook. The field `Discount` is in the same sheet thought.

Comment: If you delete the formula and make it refer only the discount, like this `=Discount`, then run the Java code would it work?

Comment: Unfortunately, the sheet is private and I can't edit it but if I set the formula with `apache-poi` it is working, but it is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: @antonionikolov - you can always create an empty excel workbook, write 2 namespaces and try it there.

Comment: In a new document, it is working. But why it is it giving this error. Strange... It is a pretty complex document, but good that now I know this is not the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @antonionikolov - anything is possible. From writing the `o` in `Discount` with Cyrillic/Greek to whatever else...

Comment: I think I found the problem. There is a hidden sheet in this workbook where The `Discount` cell is referred, but it looks like this `Discount` when it should be `'Quote services'!Discount`.